# XSLT format number for fixed number of spaces

Tags: xslt

I'm sure this has a very simple answer, but I am super new to xslt and have searched but cannot find the answer to my specific question.  Am hoping someone can point me in the right direction please?
Also if you have any suggestions on how to get better and more informed about xslt I'm open!

I have 10 spaces that needs to return a right justified, zero fill number that includes 2 decimal places (does not need to show decimal) and include the negative sign when applicable.

```
   <Period_Creditable_Hours><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(wd:Payroll_Results/wd:Period_Creditable_Hours) * 100,'0000000000')"/></Period_Creditable_Hours>
```

Returns:                   -0000003125
I need it to return:       -000003125

Thanks!
Jenn

Comment: Final version that worked - thanks all!     <Period_Creditable_Hours><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(wd:Payroll_Results/wd:Period_Creditable_Hours) * 100,'0000000000;-000000000')"/></Period_Creditable_Hours>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-format-number for all the glory details (at least in the latest and current version of XPath), basically you can specify a separate subpicture for negative numbers by using e.g. `'0000000000;-000000000'` instead of `'0000000000'`.

Comment: The pattern left of the semicolon is used for positive numbers and the one on the right for negative ones. So in your case the XSLT would be `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(wd:Payroll_Results/wd:Period_Creditable_Hours) * 100,'0000000000;000000000')"/>`

Comment: Thank you!  I believe you meant to add a dash as the first character for the right side, so I made that correction and it worked!  TYTYTY